# Drawing 45 Degree angle with CSS3

Tags: css, css-shapes

I'm trying to draw a 45 degree angle with CSS, the first image is what i'm trying to achieve, the second is what i've managed.  I can't figure out how to cut the outside of the angle by another 45 degrees (see dotted red line).

[image]

```css
.flick .text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
}
.flick {
  background-color: #055468;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 140px;
  padding: 15px;
}
.flick:before {
  background: #055468;
  content: "";
  height: 100px;
  margin: -65px 0 0 -90px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: skew(45deg);
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flick"><span class="text">Hello world</span></div>
```

Comment: You might actually want to look into `rotateZ` instead of `skew`, as this is the skewing effect in action...

Comment: @somethinghere thank you, yes chaning to transform: rotateZ(45deg); and changing widths/margings works perfect!

Comment: Ow darnit I just made an example :( Ah well, have a look at my answer below and good luck!

Comment: @somethinghere thanks for taking the time, easy when you know how ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use `rotate` instead of `skew` for this. I have also changed the position of your `:before` element so its bottom right corner lines up with the bottom left corner of your `flick` class and then set the `transform origin` to the shared corner, creating exactly the effect you wanted (I also moved it away from the top so the effect would be visible):

```css
.flick .text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
}
.flick {
   margin-top: 200px;
  background-color: #055468;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 140px;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
.flick:before {
  background: #055468;
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 100%;
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flick"><span class="text">Hello world</span></div>
```